Reference request: multi-foliated systems?
Thinking about multi-foliated systems i.e. a system of foliations of the same manifold that intersect. Specificially I am curious if this type of thing is typically studied.
In which specific setting or context are multi-foliated systems of $3$-manifolds studied? I am only interested in references of peer-reviewed publications.
An example of this is a $3$-cube foliated $3$ times (with three mutually orthogonal "stacks" of planes). It seems to me that nearly always mathematicians or field theorists only use three sets of planar slices each orthogonal which makes sense because you decompose into a nice form, but why not use more general surfaces than multiple orthogonal stacks of planes?

The only places I know are in the context of "Thurston's norm" on 2nd homology. It should be already in Thurston's original paper in Memoirs of AMS.
